# Differences between "mime-encoding" and "character encoding"

Tags: character-encoding

I was wondering what the differences are between "mime-encoding" and "character encoding"? Are they both for encoding used in text files?

I picked up "mime-encoding" from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48151/is-there-a-way-to-tell-what-encoding-is-used-for-the-name-and-content-of-a-file/48152#48152).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that MIME refers to [Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) which, from the fact that it is referred to as Internet Mail should give you an idea as to how old it is.

Usually it is a way of placing information into an email message that otherwise might not 'work'.  For example, I believe that email messages are required to be 7-bit clean.  MIME is an extension for placing information into an email message like files, HTML format email, or email content with special characters.  Typically this is done by encoding the files and using headers and other markers within the content to delineate which portions of the email correspond to what encodings, types, and file names.

I would say that MIME-encoded files may be character encoded... that may be the relationship you're looking for.